# Find $\overline{\lim}\limits_{x\rightarrow0}$ and $\underline{\lim}\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}$of $f(x)=\sin(x) \sin(1/x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

> Find the $\overline{\lim}_{x\rightarrow0}$ and $\underline{\lim}_{x\rightarrow 0}$
>   for the function $f(x)=\sin (x) \sin (\frac{1}{x})$ , $x\in(0,1) $.

My attempt:
 $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\sin(x)\sin (1/x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\frac{\sin (1/x)}{1/x}=1$ so both upper limit and lower limit are equal.  Am I right?

Comment: Check your limit of $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(1/x)}{1/x}$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr ...$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(1/x)}{1/x}$=1 is right

Comment: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\sin(1/x)}{1/x}=\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sin(y)}{y}=0$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr...really so thanks..i got where i did mistake and so both upper and limit is 0

Comment: What is upper and lower limit? I have never seen the notation $\overline{\lim}_{x\rightarrow0}\;$. Is it the same as $\lim_{x \to 0^+}$?

Comment: @Ovi...upper limit also called limit superior

Comment: these notions  of limsup and liminf coincide with the one we know one sequence if we replace the function by sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Note the following:

> **Lemma** if $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x) = \ell$ then 
>   $$\overline{\lim}\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x) =  \underline{\lim}\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x) =\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x) = \ell$$

Since, $$|f(x)|=|\sin (x) \sin (\frac{1}{x}) | \le |\sin x|\to 0~~as ~~x\to 0$$
then the limsup and liminf exist and coincide that is:

$$\overline{\lim}\limits_{x\rightarrow0}f(x) =  \underline{\lim}\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x) =\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x) = 0$$